# Please explain how the below code is working when we use rank.avg function in excel

Tags: excel, rounding, ranking, rank

I have 3 columns namely date, orders_placed and order amount in column A,C,E respectively.

In B2,D2,F2 I enter the below formula:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(RANK.AVG(B2,B$2:B10, TRUE) / ((COUNT(B$2:B10) +1 ) / 5), 0) + 1
```

Can anyone explain to me what the above code does in layman terms and math behind it?

Comment: Looks like the formula returns 1 if the number in the list is in the first 20% of the data, 2 if it is in the 20%-40% range, etc. `COUNT` counts the amount of cells in a range that contain numbers. `RANK.AVG` returns the rank of a number in a list of numbers, where any duplicate ranks will be averaged. So `RANK.AVG()/(COUNT()/5)` to me looks like it is returning the rank in a list where the highest rank is normalized to 5. Then the `ROUNDDOWN` will round the number down to the nearest integer. I didn't test this but generally this seems to be what is going on.

Comment: Sometimes you have to deconstruct the parts to work out what happens, so (COUNT(B$2:B10) +1 ) / 5) divides the total by 5.

Comment: @SolarMike thanks a lot understood your point, but what about 0 and 1 at the end ??

Comment: @SuhasU That 0 is for the rounddown()... Think about the 1...